# DLL Load Failed on Geopandas Import in Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, geopandas

I have created a virtual environment called 'geoenv' and have loaded that with three packages, Fiona, GDAL, and Geopandas. What I'm trying to accomplish is a simple import statement for Geopandas and I get "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found."

Before I launch Jupyter Notebooks, I set the environment in CMD to be the new virtual env 'geoenv' and when I go into Jupyter and open an new notebook, I see this new environment listed, but when I select it and try some code to import Geopandas, I still get the import error; same with Fiona.

I also tried using this code which has popped up on multiple SE and help blogs around this issue, but again, has not changed anything.

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name geo_env
```

What else should I be trying in order to import Geopandas in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install jupyter in the virtual environment. Then inside the virtual environment, strart the jupyter server and import geopandas.

Comment: I installed jupyter within the virtual environment using 'pip install jupyter notebook', restarted jupyter notebook, opened nb under virtual env and I'm still getting the same 'dll load failed' error.

Comment: Did you have any issues installing the packages? Did you used pip or conda?

Comment: No issues installing. I used these wheel files in Pip:
GDAL-3.2.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Fiona-1.8.18-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
geopandas-0.8.2-py3-none-any.whl

Comment: Try to download the tar.gz from conda-forge (the files contains the binaries) and install them with conda install package-name.tar.bz.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without Anaconda? I'm using pip

Comment: Installed Anaconda and with the necessary steps, got geopandas to import without error. Thanks!